# Python S3 client put_object fails silently

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload, boto3

I have implemented a mechanism to store json files to an s3 bucket.

After some time I noticed that some of the files did not exist in the bucket,there was no indication of error or some other failure whatsoever.

The problem seems to happen at random and is not consistent.
I looked it up and found people that had similar problems with s3's put_object failing silently so i implemented a retry mechanism using the file's md5 hash and ETag to verify the upload as well as checking whether the file now resides in the bucket using list_objects_v2.

Even after taking these measures though the missing file problems still persists. I have checked that the hashes match and the file is listed.

Did anyone ever have a similar problem or has some insight as to what might be the cause?
Thank you.

Edit: This is the method that uploads the file and checks the hash

```
def save_and_check_md5(s3_file_key, merged_data, packet_md5, dest, S3, DEST_BUCKETS):
    s3_response = S3.put_object(
        Bucket=DEST_BUCKETS[dest],
        Body=json.dumps(merged_data, separators=(",", ":")),
        Key=s3_file_key,
    )
    return s3_response.get("ETag") == '"{}"'.format(packet_md5), s3_response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"]
```

The method that checks whether the file has been uploaded:

```
    def file_uploaded_to_s3(key, S3, destination):
        response = S3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=destination, Prefix=key)
        for item in response.get("Contents", []):
           if item == key:
              return True
        print("File was not found in {}".format(destination))
        return False
```

And the retry part of the main method:

```
    while retries <= max_retries and not (file_uploaded_to_s3(s3_file_key, S3, destination)):
        saved_correctly, s3_status_code = save_and_check_md5(s3_file_key, merged_data, packet_md5, destination, S3
        )
        print("S3 response status code: {}".format(s3_status_code))
        if saved_correctly:
           break
        retries += 1
```

Comment: Can you properly indent your code?

Comment: I think you want `if item['Key'] == key`

Comment: @Marcin did so, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @jordanm You are correct, this was an oversight on my part, i posted the correct code

Comment: what creates the s3_file_key?  perhaps there is a bug that that value is not what you expect.  I have a feeling it is more likely there is a bug in your code/processes than AWS is randomly not uploading files.  You shouldn't need the retry logic and your code looks fine but you only provided a snippet that takes lots of parameters, maybe review the code that calls this function and add some logs around all those parameters that you can monitor and verify that they are meeting your expectations

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem?